# Replacing a non-native app with a native app in android

Tags: android, flash, replace, air, google-play

I have a feeling I already know the answer to this, but I'm still hoping it's possible.  Awhile back, I made an app for android using an Adobe Flash trial.  Since then, I've made numerous similar apps in Android Studio, which look much nicer and don't require the user to download AIR.  For whatever reason, the app I made in Flash is doing really well, despite the fact that it's easily the worst one I've made.  What I'd like to do is replace the app with a remade, nicer looking, native version of it.  Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Yes...? Are you seeing a particular obstacle? You made the original app, you know how to make native apps, and you seem to have ideas on how to improve the original. What's stopping you from remaking it natively?

Comment: @kabuko he needs to know how to replace the AIR app with native app, i guess. am i right @donursorelse?

Comment: The obstacle seems to be that I'm not sure how to generate the same certificate for the new app.  I don't see .jdk files from when I made the Flash app, so I'm not sure how to generate an identical certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The only requirements Google has for Google Play is that your application have the same package name (e.g. "com.example.myapp") and is signed with the same certificate. It also requires a new, higher version code and will prompt a user for a manual update if it requires additional permissions.

Google does not compare the contents of the APKs for similarity, so do what you want as long as you have your certificate.

But - is your "app" an app or a webpage? The Adobe AIR APK is a native app. They just provide a framework and toolset for constructing apps.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128cdca935b-8000.html

More specifically, Adobe uses the same distribution method for AIR apps as native apps, so re-distributing as a native app is possible:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac-77bd3ea112e2c0a7ed0-8000.html

Comment: A "Native App" in this instance refers to an app written in Java using the Android SDK. Adobe AIR does not do this. On Android, AIR runs essentially as an emulator for Flash. There is a massive difference between an AIR app and a native Java app. Also worth noting that AIR prefixes all app IDs with "air." on Android so the OP will need to change their app ID to be "air.com.domain.project" rather than "com.domain.project" as is currently their set ID

Comment: The question is related to distribution - can you use the Adobe AIR "app" that's in Google Play to distribute a non-AIR app. If you replace the AIR APK with a non-AIR APK, Google will allow it and there is nothing inherent to Android OS that would cause runtime or other failures. I edited my post to help better explain the perspective.

Comment: I was pointing out that your statement that "Adobe AIR should be a native app" is incorrect. The actual Adobe AIR app IS native, yes, but AIR-built apps are not. They are Flash, plain and simple. That being said, you haven't needed to use the Adobe AIR app on Android in a few years now, thanks to Captive Runtime, which bundles the runtime in the AIR-built app if chosen at compile-time. You are right that what he wants is possible (albeit with the app id modification I mentioned), I was just pointing out a discrepancy in your answer.

Comment: I see your point - I edited my statement to refer to the install file, not the contents of it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Ok. Making it with the same package is easy enough.  How do I sign it with the same certificate, though? I don't see a .jdk generated from the Flash version.

Comment: You created an AIR apk, right? The new APK must be signed with the same certificate. This might help you: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f72.html